# Programmatically add style trigger

Tags: wpf, triggers

Can anyone please help how to programatically add the following style:

```
<style>
 <style.Triggers>
     <Trigger Binding="{Binding CustomerId}" Value ="1"/>
     <setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
 </style.Triggers>
</style>
```

Comment: @Kishore - code was there, but incorrectly formatted.

Comment: Can anyone edit it to be valid - setter should be Setter and within the Trigger tag

Comment: @ronald-yoh: Paste this question in Google. The first link is what you want.

Comment: this is invalid XAML. Trigger doesn't have Binding and Setter should be child of trigger

Comment: @Andrey: It should be a DataTrigger.

Answer (score 21):

Your XAML is incorrect, but I guess you want to see this:

```
Style st = new Style();

DataTrigger tg = new DataTrigger()
{
    Binding = new Binding("CustomerId"),
    Value = 1
};

tg.Setters.Add(new Setter()
{
    Property = Control.BackgroundProperty,
    Value = ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("Red")
});

st.Triggers.Add(tg);
```

Comment: It's better to use `Value=Brushes.Red`. Thank's for answer!