# Same setters for different triggers

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers

I have several elements and all of them should look the same if "X". The problem is, "X" is different for each element, so I can't easily use a shared style for them. But in all cases, the setters are the same, so I would like to have them all in one place. How can I achieve that?

More concretely, I have this code:

```
<TextBlock Name="text1">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedMonth, Converter={conv:IsNullConverter}}"
                             Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="RoyalBlue" />
                    <!-- possibly other setters -->
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock Name="text2">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="RoyalBlue" />
                    <!-- possibly other setters, same ones as above -->
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Here, I would like to put the two `Setter`s to some common place, so that I wouldn't have to always change them one by one. Is there some way to do that?

I tried putting a collection of `Setter` together and then using something like `DataTrigger.Setters="{StaticResource SharedSetters}"`. This doesn't work, but if it did, it would be exactly what I want.

Comment: You can't set Setters direct because it is readonly property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you could have a common style which would be the base (BasedOn attribute) for all the other styles. This style would contain a normal Trigger which is controlled by a custom boolean attached property, and the setters you want to reuse. Then, in the other styles, which are based on the base style, your DataTriggers would only set the attached property, and let the base style set all the other properties.

Assuming you have created the attached property `IsSelected` on the type `Foo`, the base style would look something like:

```
<Style x:Key="IsSelectedStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="local:Foo.IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="RoyalBlue" />
            <!-- possibly other setters -->
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And then you would use it like this:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource IsSelectedStyle}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="local:Foo.IsSelected" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: And why would that be a problem?

Comment: Sorry I don't get your correct. It will work but looks а little bit sophisticated.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed. It took me a while to figure out how to bind to the attached property, so I added some code to your answer.

Comment: Good job about the code. I just edited it to show how I imagined the base style, I think that way it is simpler. In fact, a normal Trigger can access an attached property on the styled element simply by specifying the property name, no need for a binding and RelativeSource.

Answer (score 1):

Move value of your setters to static resources and set key in setters.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="keyName" Color="RoyalBlue" />
```

and

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource keyName}" />
```

in your code.

Now you can change brush of "keyName" and it affects all setters.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to avoid. If I decide I also want to change `Foreground`, this means I need to modify each trigger.

Comment: @svick In this case you need to move your code from XAML to C# and do something like next - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3193633/182344