# DataGrid, add style trigger responsible for mouse events to programatically added column

Tags: wpf, datagrid, triggers

I have DataGrid with programatically added columns in this way:

```
                var column = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn
                {
                    Header = _info.GetProcessingUnit(j).Code,
                    Binding = new Binding("Coef" + j)
                };

                var styleCellItem = new System.Windows.Style(typeof (DataGridCell));
                styleCellItem.Setters.Add(new System.Windows.Setter
                {
                    Property = DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty,
                    Value = new Binding("AssignedColor" + j),
                });
                column.CellStyle = styleCellItem;

                dg.Columns.Add(column);
```

I also need to add such a style:

```
 <Style.Triggers>
     <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True" />
     </Trigger>
 </Style.Triggers>
```

Probably it should start with something like this:

```
            styleCellItem.Triggers.Add(new System.Windows.Trigger
```

but i don't know how to write it.

Comment: How about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193452/programatically-add-style-trigger?rq=1) question?

Comment: @MikeEason , i had seen it, but it is different.