# C# WPF Add Style Object To Cells In Datagrid Using Trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Using the answer from this thread [Programmatically add style trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193452/programmatically-add-style-trigger)

```
Style st = new Style();

DataTrigger tg = new DataTrigger()
{
    Binding = new Binding("PackageTechnology_c"),
    Value = "Plastic"
};

tg.Setters.Add(new Setter()
{
    Property = Control.BackgroundProperty,
    Value = ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("Red")
});

st.Triggers.Add(tg);
```

I want to be able to add styles and trigger to my Datagrid at run time. Once I have created this style object, how to I add the style to my datagrid? I am not looking to do this in the XML, since I am dynamically creating styles are runtime. How do I do this with code-behind?

I tried:

```
datagrid.Style = st;
```

which results in this:
[image: style]

If I do:

```
datagrid.CellStyle = st;
```

then I get this:
[image]

But what I want is for the cell that has the value: "Plastic" inside the column "Package Technology" to turn red. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: `datagrid.Style = st` *is* how you would assign a `Style` in code. If that's not working, there must be something else wrong. Take a look at the rest of your code and maybe post some more of it for us to see.

Comment: @KeithStein Actually you are correct. That is the way to apply the ```Style```. It's just that I didn't understand what ```Style``` I was applying to my datagrid. I've added images and reframed my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`DataGridColumn.CellStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.cellstyle). It will apply the given `Style` to all cells in that specific column, instead of every cell in the `DataGrid`.

Since you're auto-generating your columns, you would make use of the [`DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn) event. It gets raised for each auto-generated column when it gets created. You can use the argument to check which column is being created, and if it is the `PackageTechnologyc` column then you would create and set the `Style`.

If you were defining your columns in XAML, you would have `<DataGrid Name="datagrid" ...`, and then somewhere later `<DataGridTextColumn Header="PackageTechnologyc"...`. In that case you'd just add a `Name` to the `DataGridTextColumn` and then reference it like so: `packageTechnologyColumn.Style = st;`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question Keith, I really appreciate your help.
Unfortunately, I am populating my DataGrid using a DataTable like so: ```datagrid.DataContext = datatable.DefaultView;```
There are too many columns in my datatable to define the columns manually in the XML file. So I don't have access to the DataGridColumn object.

Comment: The point at which I am running this code during the initialization of the class seems to be before any of the columns are initialized in ```datagrid.Columns``` too, [seen during debugging](https://i.imgur.com/YRpgrUI.png)

Comment: @function9 Oh, okay. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been trying to figure out a way to do this for days. I'm crying tears of joy. Setting the style inside the AutoGeneratingColumn event was exactly what I was looking for and it worked perfectly. Thank you for taking the time to help me.